# VSTO Error System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

When I try to debug Excel workbook (VSTO) in Visual studio 2015 Enterprice, I get following error,

[image]

From: file:///c:/users/sameera.madhusanka/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/ClassLibrary1/ExcelWorkbook2/bin/Debug/ExcelWorkbook2.vsto

The exception text:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
>
> at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
>
> at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore()
>
> at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)
>
> at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
>
> at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
>
> at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager..ctor(Uri deploymentSource, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isConfirmed, DownloadOptions downloadOptions, AsyncOperation optionalAsyncOp)
>
> at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager..ctor(Uri deploymentManifest, Boolean launchInHostProcess)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.IPHMProxy..ctor(Uri uri)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.get_Proxy()
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Comment: Isn't it just you haven't marked the file to be copied? Thus it exists only in your code repository, and not in your compiled version? 

Look the the files properties in your solution explorer, property explorer, and then select "Copy Always" that should fix it yes?

Comment: thanks Morten, I changed them to copy locally.
but it still showing the error...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one or more of the files in your deployment. Most probably you have something installed in the GAC on other machines, but the current one doesn't have a component or referenced assembly installed.

You can try turning on the enhanced logging and checking out the results. It might pinpoint exactly what file is missing. You can read more about this in the [Enhanced Logging in ClickOnce Deployment](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/enhanced-logging-in-clickonce-deployment/) article. Also I've found a similar forum thread - [GetUserStore throws FileNotFoundException](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9f3f511f-4f16-43c0-b860-90d40aa65e92/getuserstore-throws-filenotfoundexception?forum=winformssetup).